# Group Python List Elements

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy

I have a python list as follows:

```
my_list = 

 [[25, 1, 0.65],
 [25, 3, 0.63],
 [25, 2, 0.62],
 [50, 3, 0.65],
 [50, 2, 0.63], 
 [50, 1, 0.62]]
```

I want to order them according to this rule:

```
1 --> [0.65, 0.62] <--25, 50
2 --> [0.62, 0.63] <--25, 50
3 --> [0.63, 0.65] <--25, 50
```

So the expected result is as follows:

```
Result = [[0.65, 0.62],[0.62, 0.63],[0.63, 0.65]]
```

How to do it guys?

I tried as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list,columns=['a','b','c'])
res = df.groupby(['b', 'c']).get_group('c')
print res

ValueError: must supply a tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @ettanany I tried some ways but failed. What is the easiest way to solving this kind of problem?

Comment: Check my answer below and let me know if that's what you want.

Comment: thanks, upvoted but for large lists, seems difficult to use.do you use pandas?

Comment: I do not use pandas, my below answer uses some python features / functions (list comprehension, zip, sorted, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your list with native python, but I find it easiest to get your required list using numpy. Since you were going to use pandas anyway, I consider this to be an acceptable solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np
# or just use pandas.np if you have that already imported

my_list = [[25, 1, 0.65],
 [25, 3, 0.63],
 [25, 2, 0.62],
 [50, 3, 0.65],
 [50, 2, 0.63],
 [50, 1, 0.62]]

sorted_list = sorted(my_list,key=itemgetter(1,0)) # sort by second and first column
sliced_array = np.array(sorted_list)[:,-1].reshape(-1,2)
final_list = sliced_array.tolist() # to get a list
```

The main point is to use `itemgetter` to sort your list on two columns one after the other. The resulting sorted list contains the required elements in its third column, which I extract with numpy. It could be done with native python, but if you're already using numpy/pandas, this should be natural.

Comment: @jean it might, but why? Your original data is not in a dataframe, at least it doesn't look like that in your question. I don't think it's necessary to put together a dataframe just to do the sorting if you can do the same in native python. Too much unnecessary overhead, at least that's what I'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
my_list = [[25, 1, 0.65], [25, 3, 0.63], [25, 2, 0.62], [50, 3, 0.65], [50, 2, 0.63], [50, 1, 0.62]]

list_25 = sorted([item for item in my_list if item[0] == 25], key=lambda item: item[1])
list_50 = sorted([item for item in my_list if item[0] == 50], key=lambda item: item[1])

res = [[i[2], j[2]] for i,j in zip(list_25, list_50)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[[0.65, 0.62], [0.62, 0.63], [0.63, 0.65]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this with pandas is to extract each group, pull out `'c'`, convert to a list and append to the list you want :

```
z = []
>>> for g in df.groupby('b'):
        z.append(g[1]['c'].tolist())

>>> z
[[0.65, 0.62], [0.62, 0.63], [0.63, 0.65]]
```

You could do this as a list comprehension:

```
>>> res = [g[1]['c'].tolist() for g in df.groupby('b')]

>>> res
[[0.65, 0.62], [0.62, 0.63], [0.63, 0.65]]
```

Another way would be to `apply` `list` directly to `df.groupby('b')['c']` this gives you the object you need. Then call the `.tolist()` method to return a list of lists:

```
>>> df.groupby('b')['c'].apply(list).tolist()
[[0.65000000000000002, 0.62], [0.62, 0.63], [0.63, 0.65000000000000002]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) has a one-liner for these kind of problems:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
my_list = np.asarray(my_list)
keys, table = npi.Table(my_list[:, 1], my_list[:, 0]).mean(my_list[:, 2])
```

Note that if duplicate values are present in the list, the mean is reported in the table.

EDIT: added some improvements to the master of numpy_indexed, that allow more control over the way you convert to a table; for instance, there is Table.unique which asserts that each item in the table occurs once in the list, and Table.sum; and eventually all other reductions supported by the numpy_indexed package that make sense. Hopefully I can do a new release for that tonight.